# Raspberry Pi : UI development using QT

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi

I am a new to rasberry pi and Qt. I want to start building a small UI using Qt.

I would like to know whether Rasberry Pi supports interfacing a display device and is there any board or evaluation kit , which helps me building a UI using Qt.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. There are for Debian Jessy Qt-packages as official built, so you can use them.

Or you rely on these nice scripts:
https://github.com/neuronalmotion/qtrpi
Allowing you to build almost without interaction Qt 5.10 on RPi as well as building the libs for cross-compiling.

So, yes. Qt works on RPi. Attaching a display unit as well.